# Link Cairo and R

Tags: r, cairo

I have built and installed libcairo2-dev from source on a machine without apt-get or sudo, but cannot get R to see the Cairo header files (for `install.packages('Cairo')` to work).  My end goal is R working with Cairo, and building this way and linking Cairo to R is the best route I see.  Thoughts on how to get R to see my built Cairo?

R encounters the error below from `install.packages('Cairo')`, but I see the required file in the flag requested by the error message.

```
configure: CAIRO_CFLAGS=-L/app/vendor/cairo/include/cairo
checking if R was compiled with the RConn patch... no
checking cairo.h usability... no
checking cairo.h presence... no
checking for cairo.h... no
configure: error: Cannot find cairo.h! Please install cairo (http://www.cairographics.org/) and/or set CAIRO_CFLAGS/LIBS correspondingly.
```

vs

```
~/vendor/cairo/include/cairo $ pwd
/app/vendor/cairo/include/cairo
~/vendor/cairo/include/cairo $ ls
cairo-deprecated.h  cairo-ft.h  cairo-pdf.h  cairo-svg.h      cairo-xlib.h
cairo-features.h    cairo.h cairo-ps.h   cairo-version.h
```

variants such as -L/app/vendor/cairo and the like also fail.  My amateur theory is that the preexisting libcairo2 install (which lacks header files) is faking out the install.packages call.

My sessionInfo():

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 2.15.1 (2012-06-22)
Platform: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=C                 LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably a little late since you may already solved the problem, but it seems that CAIRO_CFLAGS is being set incorrectly. You are trying to include cairo.h and not trying to link it (I think). So it should technically be:

```
CAIRO_CFLAGS=-I/app/vendor/cairo/include/cairo
```

Note the "-I" instead of "-L" as you had stated. Are you setting the CAIRO_CLAGS by yourself? Or is this something being set for you? Normally, you shouldn't need to set it (at least I don't).

HTH.